# Why my script is returning me twice the objects?

Tags: powershell

I'm doing some learning experimentation about the pipeline and I've built myself 3 function: The-Getter, Do-Something, Output-Somewhere.

With my getter function, I'm trying to output 3 object that has only a name property. It's kind of working except my results will be duplicated (displayed twice).

I'm wondering what I did wrong here:

```
function The-Getter {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param()

begin{
Write-Verbose -Message 'Entering the begin bloc of The-Getter'
$a = 'BMW X3'
$b = 'BMW X4'
$c = 'BMW X6'
}

process{
Write-Verbose -Message "Entering the process bloc of The-Getter with object $_"
$Collection = @()
$obj1 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$obj1 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($a) –passthru
$Collection += ($obj1)

$obj2 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$obj2 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($b) –passthru
$Collection += ($obj2)

$obj3 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$obj3 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($c) –passthru
$Collection += ($obj3)

Return $Collection
}

end{
Write-Verbose -Message 'Entering the end bloc of The-Getter'
}
}
```

Output is :

```
PS C:\> The-Getter

Name
----
BMW X3
BMW X4
BMW X6
BMW X3
BMW X4
BMW X6
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has come from your calls to `Add-Member` which is returning the Object. Since you do nothing with the returned object, it prints.

If you combine `$Collection +=` with `Add-Member` lines the issue should go away:

```
$obj2 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$Collection += $obj2 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($b) –passthru
```

But really, you can get rid of `$Collection` altogether:

```
process{
Write-Verbose -Message "Entering the process bloc of The-Getter with object $_"
$obj1 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$obj1 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($a) –passthru
$obj2 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$obj2 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($b) –passthru
$obj3 = New-Object –typename PSObject
$obj3 | Add-Member –membertype NoteProperty –name Name –value ($c) –passthru
}
```